# How do I use "virsh shutdown" on KVM domains to shut down Ubuntu guests?

Tags: virtualization, shutdown, kvm-virtualization

I am using various KVM domains on a Ubuntu server. Both the host and guests run 10.04.1, 2.6.32-24 kernel, virsh reports version 0.7.5, KVM 0.12.3. The guests boot automatically when the host boots and they have `<features><acpi/><features>` in their configuration.

I could never manage to make `virsh shutdown MyDomain` on the host to have any effect. It responds with `Domain MyDomain is being shutdown` and the domain keeps happily running. `virsh list` still lists them in the state `running`.

`virsh destroy MyDomain` works fine, but of course that's not really what I want, so most of the time I log into each one and shut them down manually, which is pretty annoying.

I couldn't really find any information on how `virsh shutdown` tries to shut the domain down. Pointers to useful bits of documentation are welcome.

What could cause this? How is it supposed to work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check to see if you have the [package acpid](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/acpid) installed on each of the guests.

I generally create new virtual machines using [VMBuilder](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/vmbuilder.1.html) with the parameter `--addpkg acpid` and the only time I've had trouble shutting down Ubuntu guests using `virsh` was when the guest vm had crashed in some way.

Comment: Awesome, that's all it took! I added that to my VMBuilder script as well now.  

Did I miss an important piece of documentation here, or are you just magically assumed to know that? In retrospect, it makes sense to me, I guess `virsh shutdown` is just the equivalent to pressing the power button on a physical box. But that I haven't seen mentioned anywhere either, or I might have connected the dots and investigated more in that direction...  

Either way, thanks a lot! (Will upvote when I get the necessary rep.)

Comment: I know that it is mentioned in the Server Guide section on vmbuilder very close to the end of the article. I'm not aware if it is mentioned elsewhere. https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/jeos-and-vmbuilder.html

Comment: I must have not read it to the end. *blush* Or maybe I'll just pretend it wasn't there when I originally set most of these VMs up (8.04 or so). :P

Comment: Note for Debian: if you disabled installation of _Recommended_ packages, then `acpid` alone does not much because it only contains the binaries. You need to install `acpi-support-base` package to handle power button ACPI events. For Ubuntu, `acpid` contains both binaries and base event handlers and is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have that option, there are 'shutdown modes' you can utilize to trigger a shutdown

```
$ sudo virsh shutdown --help
OPTIONS
[--domain] <string>  domain name, id or uuid
--mode <string>  shutdown mode: acpi|agent|initctl|signal|paravirt
```

i.e.,

```
sudo virsh shutdown domain1 --mode acpi
```